# Oracle multiple PIVOT clauses

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have data with 2 calculated bucket columns I would like to summarize with a PIVOT query.  This is an example set of pre-generated data.  My bucket columns here are sec and pct.

```
select '1' id, 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec' sec, 'lt_25_pct' pct from dual
union all
select '2', 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct' from dual
union all
select '3', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct' from dual
union all
select '4', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct' from dual
union all
select '5', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct' from dual
union all
select '6', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct' from dual
```

The output should look like this

| cat | lt_1_sec | lt_2_sec | lt_25_pct | lt_50_pct | lt_75_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

I would like to pivot on the values of both sec and pct independently.  I am able to use a pivot clause to accomplish this on one or the other, or a permutation of all values of sec by all values of pct, but not both independently and simultaneously.

I have tried multiple pivot clauses, which creates some unexpected behavior, multiple values in the pivot-for clause, which creates a permutation of all values, and multiple aggregation functions, which only performs multiple aggregation options over a single column.

Non-functional example one with multiple pivot clauses (the data returned is incorrect):

```
with dummy_data as (
                     select cat, sec, pct
                     from (
                            select '1' id, 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec' sec, 'lt_25_pct' pct
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '2', 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '3', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '4', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '5', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '6', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct'
                            from dual
                          )
                   ),
     dummy_pvt as (
                    select *
                    from dummy_data pivot (count(*) for (sec) in ('lt_1_sec' as lt_1_sec,
                      'lt_2_sec' as lt_2_sec)) pivot (count(*) for (pct) in ('lt_25_pct' as lt_25_pct,
                      'lt_50_pct' as lt_50_pct,
                      'lt_75_pct' as lt_75_pct))
                  )
select cat, sum(lt_1_sec), sum(lt_2_sec), sum(lt_25_pct), sum(lt_50_pct), sum(lt_75_pct)
from dummy_pvt
group by cat;
```

| CAT | SUM(LT_1_SEC) | SUM(LT_2_SEC) | SUM(LT_25_PCT) | SUM(LT_50_PCT) | SUM(LT_75_PCT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Non-functional example two with multiple pivot-for values (should not product a permutation of all value combinations)

```
with dummy_data as (
                     select cat, sec, pct
                     from (
                            select '1' id, 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec' sec, 'lt_25_pct' pct
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '2', 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '3', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '4', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '5', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '6', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct'
                            from dual
                          )
                   )
select *
from dummy_data pivot (count(*) for (sec, pct) in (
  ('lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct') as lt_1_25, 
  ('lt_1_sec', 'lt_50_pct') as lt_1_50, 
  ('lt_1_sec', 'lt_75_pct') as lt_1_75, 
  ('lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct') as lt_2_25,
  ('lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct') as lt_2_50,
  ('lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct') as lt_2_75));
```

| CAT | LT_1_25 | LT_1_50 | LT_1_75 | LT_2_25 | LT_2_50 | LT_2_75 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Non-functional example three with multiple aggregate functions (only creates columns for the sec values)

```
with dummy_data as (
                     select cat, sec, pct
                     from (
                            select '1' id, 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec' sec, 'lt_25_pct' pct
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '2', 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '3', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '4', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '5', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '6', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct'
                            from dual
                          )
                   )
select *
from dummy_data pivot (count(sec) sec_cnt, count(pct) pct_cnt for (sec) in (
  ('lt_1_sec') as lt_1_sec,
  ('lt_2_sec') as lt_2_sec));
```

| CAT | LT_1_SEC_SEC_CNT | LT_1_SEC_PCT_CNT | LT_2_SEC_SEC_CNT | LT_2_SEC_PCT_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 |

Is there really no way to perform multiple pivots over separate sets of values in the same query without permutating the values?

| group |  | pivot_1_a | pivot_1_b |  | pivot_2_x | pivot_2_y | pivot_2_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | cnt_a | cnt_b |  | cnt_x | cnt_y | cnt_z |

Where A+B = X+Y+Z = count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same query? yes.

Same `pivot`? no.

**note** The table alias goes *after* the `pivot`

(You'll also need to remove the duplicate `cat` column)

```sql
with data as (
                            select '1' id, 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec' sec, 'lt_25_pct' pct
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '2', 'a' cat, 'lt_1_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '3', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_25_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '4', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '5', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_50_pct'
                            from dual
                            union all
                            select '6', 'a' cat, 'lt_2_sec', 'lt_75_pct'
                            from dual
), data_sec as ( select cat, sec from data )
,data_pct as (select cat, pct from data )
select *
from data_sec
  pivot (
    count(sec)
    for (sec) in (
      'lt_1_sec' as lt_1_sec,
      'lt_2_sec' as lt_2_sec
    )
  ) a
  full outer join
    data_pct
      pivot (
        count(pct)
        for (pct) in (
          'lt_25_pct' as lt_25_pct,
          'lt_50_pct' as lt_50_pct,
          'lt_75_pct' as lt_75_pct,
          'lt_100_sec' as lt_100_sec
        )
      ) b
      on a.cat = b.cat
  ;
```

[image]

Comment: Strangely, the code you posted gives me a [1401] ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column.  However, if I remove the value for which there is no data (lt_100_sec) or shorten it by one character to lt_100_se then it works fine.  I'm on 19c, but possibly hitting a limit on column name length.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522337900346184952